# Overloading >> operator for a base class

Tags: c++, inheritance

So I have a base class Animal which has 2 classes inheriting from it, which are cat and dog. Both classes are redefining a pure virtual method speak which just couts "meow" for cat and "woof" for dog. In in my main function I want to be able to do some thing like this:

```
int main (void) {
  Animal a;
  dog d;

  while (cin  >> a) //is this even possible? would it be cin >> d; instead?
   cout << a << endl;



  return(0);
}
```

SO this should cout the animals speak function, but how can I go about doing so? Also, I'm confused, if you dont know the type of animal the user is going to cin then how can you determine which speak function to use, would you use a template class?

Comment: Have you tried... anything?

Comment: If your `Animal` class contains a pure virtual function, then you can't do `Animal a;` in the first place.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do something like this in base class:

```
#include <istream>

using namespace std;

class Animal
{
  friend istream & operator >> ( istream &is, Animal &animal )
  {
    animal.readFromStream(is);
    return is;
  };
protected:
  virtual void readFromStream( istream &is ) = 0;
};
```

and in derived:

```
class Dog : public Animal
{
  protected:
    virtual void readFromStream( istream &is )
    {
      // read dog
    };
};
```

Comment: Nice and to the point. You can even `return is;` for brevity if you change the return type.

Comment: but how to load the cat with `cin >> a` where `a` is just an `Animal`? (see original post)

Comment: @esskar: in this case animal should have a virtual constructor (based on the read stream): `static Animal * VirtConstructor( istream &is ) { /* generate class based on the stream, or return 0 */ };`

Comment: What would go inside readFromStream? Atm I'm doing something like is >> "dog"; but I get a load of errors about >> not being overloaded, but wasnt it already overloaded in the base class. All I want to do is be able to type dog(10, 20) as an input, where 10 is its age and 20 its weight in its constructor, and the cmd should output speak(). This input/output stream stuff is going way over my head.

Answer (score 4):

Here's an example of overriding `operator<<`, which calls a public member function `speak()`. If you need access to private members in the overloaded `operator<<`, make it a `friend`.

```
#include <iostream>

class Animal {
   public:
      virtual std::string speak(void) = 0;
};

class Dog : public Animal {
   std::string speak() { return "woof"; }
};

class Cat : public Animal {
   std::string speak() { return "meow"; }
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, Animal& a) {
    out << a.speak();
    return out;
}

int main (void) {
   Dog d;
   Cat c;

   Animal &a = d;
   std::cout << a << std::endl;

   Animal &a2 = c;
   std::cout << a2 << std::endl;

   return 0;
}
```

You should be able to work out how to do similar for `operator>>`.

> Also, I'm confused, if you dont know the type of animal the user is going to cin then how can you determine which speak function to use, would you use a template class?

That's the idea behind dynamic binding/polymorphism. `a` and `a2` are references to derived types of `Animal` and, since `speak()` is virtual, the v-table will contain a pointer to the  necessary `speak()` function for a `Dog` or `Cat` object.

Comment: "You should be able to work out how to do similar for `operator<<`." Typo? Did you mean `operator>>` ?

Comment: @Rob: woops, I had the other two the wrong way around as well in the paragraph up the top before I quickly edited it. At least I got the ones in the code right.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do precisely what you want. That is, you can't

```
Animal a;
std::cin >> a;
```

and expect the type of 'a' to change. Fundamentally, objects are not polymorphic -- pointers and references are polymorphic.

Knowing that, you **can** do something almost like what you want:

```
Animal* pA;
std::cin >> pA;
std::cout << *pA << "\n";
delete pA;
```

You can accomplish this by overloading

```
istream& operator>>(istream&, Animal*&);
```

to create (via `new`) an object of the run-time indicated type.

Consider this program:

```
#include <iostream>
class Animal {
public:
  virtual void speak(std::ostream& os) const = 0;
  virtual ~Animal() {} // must be virtual
};
class Dog : public Animal {
public:
  void speak(std::ostream& os) const { os << "woof"; }
};
class Cat : public Animal {
public:
  void speak(std::ostream& os) const { os << "meow"; }
};
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Animal& being) {
  being.speak(os);
  return os;
}

std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, Animal*& zygote) {
  std::string species;
  is >> species;

  // fetch remainder of line with std::getline()

  if(species == "cat") {
    // parse remainder of line

    // Finally, create a Cat
    zygote = new Cat;
    return is;
  }
  if(species == "dog") {
    // parse remainder of line

    // and create a Dog
    zygote = new Dog;
    return is;
  }

  // Hmm, unknown species? Probably not safe to create
  std::cerr << "Warning! Unknown species. Could be dangerous!\n";
  is.setstate(std::ios::failbit);
  zygote = 0;
  return is;
}

int main () {
  Animal *pPet;

  while(std::cin >> pPet) {
    std::cout << *pPet << "\n";
    delete pPet;
  }
}
```

Comment: This seems to work, but is there a way I can do something like:
std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, Animal*& zygote) {
 (zygote)->readFromStream( istream &is )
} Then it should call the readFromStream automatically for a type dog or cat? Then I can just create a dog object with its constructor through input stream and then it should do speak()? Currently all I get is "segment fault" from the compiler.

Answer (score 0):

for the << operator, it is kinda okay

```
friend ostream &operator<<(ostream &output, const Animal & animal)     //output
{
    return output << animal.speak();
}
```

for the input it is more complex, and i do not know if you can do it directly with `Animal`
but you could build an `AnimalLoader`

```
class AnimalLoader {
    Animal* _animal;

public:
    AnimalLoader() : _animal(NULL) { }

    ~AnimalLoader() { if(_animal) delete _animal; }

    Animal *GetAnimal() 
    {
        Animal *retval = _animal;
        _animal = NULL;
        return retval; 
    }

    friend istream & operator >> ( istream &input, AnimalLoader &animalLoader )
    {
        if(_animal) delete _animal;
        std::string animalStr;
        input >> animalStr;
        if(animalStr == "dog")
            _animal = new Dog();
        else if(animalStr == "cat")
           _animal = new Cat();
        else
           _animal = NULL;

        return input;
    }
};
```

so you can then call

```
int main (void) {
    AnimalLoader animalLoader;

    while (cin  >> animalLoader) {
        Animal *animal = animalLoader.GetAnimal();
        if(animal != NULL) {
             cout << *animal << endl;
             delete animal;
        }
        else {
             cout << "ERROR: Could not read Animal." << endl;   
        }
    }
    return(0);
}
```

**EDIT 1**
forgot to call `speak()`

**EDIT 2**
applied it to OP example

Comment: This is a terrible answer, on both counts. The first part is flat out broken (happy recursion), and the second needlessly creates tons of dynamic objects that are promptly leaked.

Comment: forgot to call `speak()` fixed it. why is the 2nd one leaking anything? the OP asked, if it is possible to read-in an Animal without knowing which animal to read; so he does need an AnimalLoader (in my opinion).